Finding value of coefficients in complex numbers
Suppose that $x , y , z$ are complex numbers of equal magnitude and satify the given below conditions:

$ x+y+z= -\frac{\sqrt3}{2} - i\sqrt5 $
$x.y.z= \sqrt3 + i\sqrt5$

If: $x = a +ib, y = c + id, z = e + if$
then the value of $(ab + cd + ef)^2$ in fractional form
My attempts thus far,

tried equating the given condition, taking magnitudes as $l$ and then equating every modulus to it,

ex: $\sqrt{a^2+b^2} = l$ | $\sqrt{c^2+d^2} = l$ | $\sqrt{e^2+f^2} = l$
and then, $(a+b)^2 - l^2 = 2ab $ and similarly for subsequent terms and puting it directly into the term whose value is required but it yielded no useful result,
secondly I tried the 2 given equations and then expanded them by multiplying and adding but it lead to a dead end as well.
Someone please read and let me know where have I been commiting errors and also help in rectifying them.

Two equations for three unknowns generally doesn't have a unique solution (barring special cases like $x^2 + y^2 = 0$).

@Dan I am afraid that is all the information I am provided with, maybe it has got to do something with the modulus? since they are all equal and can be taken as a equation right? $\sqrt{a^2+b^2} + \sqrt{c^2+d^2} + \sqrt{e^2+f^2} = constant$
and also, the value which is asked, its something different, it doesn't asks for individual values but rather a special product, maybe some way we can solve it without needing everything?

The answer is $-\frac{1}{16}\left(x^2 - \frac{4}{x^2} + y^2 - \frac{4}{y^2} + z^2 - \frac{4}{z^2}\right)^2$, if you can figure out what $x$, $y$, and $z$ are.

@underflow can you kindly post the solution? that would be very helpful thank you. I will really appreciate that

@Dan how did you to come up with that?

By taking the absolute value of equation (2), we get $|xyz| = \sqrt{8}$.  But since we're given that the three numbers are equal in magnitude, this means $|x| = |y| = |z| = \sqrt{2}$.
Now we need to find the phase angles of the three complex numbers.  Label these $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$, so that:
$$x = \sqrt{2}(\cos\alpha + i\sin\alpha)$$
$$y = \sqrt{2}(\cos\beta + i\sin\beta)$$
$$z = \sqrt{2}(\cos\gamma + i\sin\gamma)$$
Until I can come up with an algebraic solution, let's tackle the problem numerically.  Without loss of generality, assume that the alphabetical ordering of the angles corresponds to the numerical order.
Let's define the error in an approximation as the linear combination of the sum and product errors:
$$\left|x+y+z - (-\frac{\sqrt3}{2} - i\sqrt5)\right| + 11 \left|xyz - (\sqrt3 + i\sqrt5) \right|$$
Why multiply the product error by 11?  Because when I calculated the 0.1 percentile error for sum and product, the product error was smaller by about that factor, so I applied this factor so that sum and product errors would be about equal in the final result.
Using whole degrees, the total error is minimized with $\alpha = 204°$, $\beta = 231°$, and $\gamma = 337°$.
Using tenths of degrees, the total error is minimized with $\alpha = 203.2°$, $\beta = 232.3°$, and $\gamma = 336.7°$.
Using hundredths of degrees, the total error is minimized with $\alpha = 203.29°$, $\beta = 232.23°$, and $\gamma = 336.72°$.
That should be enough precision for now.  The coefficients are:
$$a \approx \sqrt{2}\cos(203.29°) \approx -1.298977$$
$$b \approx \sqrt{2}\sin(203.29°) \approx -0.559159$$
$$c \approx \sqrt{2}\cos(232.23°) \approx -0.866196$$
$$d \approx \sqrt{2}\sin(232.23°) \approx -1.117902$$
$$e \approx \sqrt{2}\cos(336.72°) \approx 1.299075$$
$$f \approx \sqrt{2}\sin(336.72°) \approx -0.558932$$
But wait: $c$ looks pretty close to $-\frac{\sqrt3}{2} \approx -0.866025$.  What if it actually is $-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$?  Then, in order to ensure that $c^2 + d^2 = 2$, we have $d = -\frac{\sqrt5}{2} \approx -1.118034$.  So then $y = -\frac{\sqrt3}{2} - i\frac{\sqrt5}{2}$.  And by substituting this into our original equations, we get:
$$x + z = -i\frac{\sqrt5}{2}$$
$$xz = -2$$
Matching up the real and imaginary parts of the first equation, we get $a + e = 0$ and $b + f = -\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}$.  But the numerical result suggests that $b = f$.  If so, then $b = f = -\frac{\sqrt{5}}{4}$.  Then from $a^2 + b^2 = 2$, we get $a = -\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{4}$, so $e = \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{4}$.
Note that $x+y+z= -\frac{\sqrt3}{2} - i\sqrt5$ and $xyz = \sqrt3 + i\sqrt5$, so the original equations are exactly satisfied.
In summary:
$$a = -\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{4} \approx -1.299038$$
$$b = -\frac{\sqrt{5}}{4} \approx -0.559017$$
$$c = -\frac{\sqrt3}{2} \approx -0.866025$$
$$d = -\frac{\sqrt5}{2} \approx -1.118034$$
$$e = \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{4} \approx 1.299038$$
$$f = -\frac{\sqrt{5}}{4} \approx -0.559017$$
So:
$$ab + cd + ef$$
$$= \left(-\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{4}\right)\left(-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{4}\right) + \left(-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\right)\left(-\frac{\sqrt5}{2}\right) + \left(\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{4}\right)\left(-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{4}\right)$$
$$= \frac{3\sqrt{15}}{16} + \frac{\sqrt{15}}{4} - \frac{3\sqrt{15}}{16}$$
$$= \frac{\sqrt{15}}{4}$$
And thus,
$$\boxed{(ab + cd + ef)^2 = \frac{15}{16}}$$
